# How do I upload photos in the background on a website?

Tags: ajax, upload, photos, image-uploading

I'm working on a website that allows users to batch upload photos. I was wondering if it's possible for them to start the upload process for a group of photos, then let the user click around and move to something else within the same site, while the images are loaded behind the scenes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) for multi-file upload. But you must stay on this page to complete request. Of course, you could allow user to load other page, but using Ajax.
The bad solution is to use iframe, where file upload will be...

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about using an iframe, but that isn't a very elegant solution. On my phone, apps can upload my whole photo library in the background while I continue navigating the around the app. I want to do that on a site.